# Java Jsoup button selection

Tags: java, html, css, jsoup

I just want to check whether given element exists or not, I have the following code:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.gsmarena.com/news.php3?iPage=2").get();
    Elements button = doc.select("a > pages-next");
        if (!button.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("contains");
        } else {
              System.out.println("not contains");
        }
```

But it always returns false, here is also the element that I want to check:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues here:

1. The right selector is `.pages-next` and not `a > pages-next`.
2. You must provide the user-agent string, or else you'll get a page with different DOM structure then the one you get with your browser.

Use this code -

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.gsmarena.com/news.php3?iPage=2")
             .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:46.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/46.0")
             .get();
        Elements button = doc.select(".pages-next");
        if (!button.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("contains");
        } else {
              System.out.println("not contains");
        }
```

Comment: aha, okay now it worked thanks, I will accept the answer in 1 min